# Is it possible to make all currently open windows minimize, whenever I open a new application?

Tags: 12.04, unity, xorg, window-manager, desktop-environments

When i **open**(not only running) an application, how to make the other windows minimized?

PS It seems i can not do it with **Devilspie**.

Thank you for your time.
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: This is a decent question but there probably isn't a realistic answer. You might edit your question with why you want to do this. There might be an easier approach that you hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot make other windows be minimized when a new Window is opened. However, you can make all other windows transparent or dark.

### Using Compiz to achieve a similar effect.

It may not be possible to minimized all other windows when a Window is opened, but you can make it seem as though all other Windows are minimized.

Before you continue, make sure to install [compiz-plugins-extra [image: Install compiz-plugins-extra]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compiz-plugins-extra).

#### Using the plugin "Dim Inactive":

- First, install [Compizconfig-Settings-Manager [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager)
- Then enable "Dim Inactive"
  [image: I like pie.]
- Under Misc. Options, do the following:
  [image: Hi!]

#### Using Compiz "Trail Focus":

- As above, if you have not already done so, install Compiz Config Settings Manager
- Enable "Trail Focus"
  [image: This, is CNN]
- Set up the options under "Behaviour" as follows:
  [image: T]
- And under "Appearance" as follows:
  [image]

### Results:

With trail focus:
[image: A]

Comment: Oh, my dear friend! Thank you so much!! PS if anybody does not have these plugins, you can install it: "sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra"

Comment: Hey Roland you just made their day! Nice answer.

Comment: @Nwbie: I was wondering if I had missed a step, lol. I'll add that.